# Can we convert a function object to String on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, function, methods

In JavaScript we have something like .toString which can convert the entire function object to string.
Do we have something similar on IOS?

For example, in JavaScript if we have function like this, after converting it with .toString and printing the value in console we see the entire function object.

```
function sum(a, b)
{ 
  return a + b;
}
console.log(sum.toString());

// expected output: 
// "function sum(a, b) 
//   {
//return a + b;
//  }"
```

Can we do something similar for IOS? I tried String (describing :Function) in Swift but that didn't work and gave me output as (Function) but not the complete structure like we get in JavaScript .toString.

```
 public func say_hello()
 {
    print("Hello, World!")
 }

String(describing: say_hello))
//Output:(Function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the many comments explaining why that's not possible (nor feasible in many cases), I want to point out that you can use JavaScript code in your Swift app and thus use the serialization mechanism of that language. Have a look at [JSContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jscontext)  for details. This of course won't make things simpler, but it does give extra flexibility with injecting/changing/extending functionality at runtime.

Comment: I can pass javascript method to the JSContext and read them in Objc/Swift.But I want to pass objc/swift to JSContext.               
Here is what i tried.

JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[context evaluateScript: @"function sum(a, b){return a + b;}"];
JSValue *function = context[@"sum"];

If I read the function object it gives me complete Javascript function structure.But how do i pass objc/swift to JSContext?

Comment: You can access Swift functions from JS and JS functions from Swift with `JSContext`. Which is not what your question was about, as became clearer thanks to the comments/chat conversation. I wanted to add the info about `JSContext` because your original question might lead other people here and they most likely don't want to serialize Swift code for security reasons, but have something JS-like in mind. Concerning your security-related intent, I think you should rephrase and post a new question that explains your intention to catch jailbroken devices tampering with your code at runtime.

Comment: Actually we have done most of the things that can be done with a static approach.We wanted to think also in dynamic approach to be more secure for which these were the building blocks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from Swift/Objc